# Child process hangs when performing inference with PyTorch model

Tags: pytorch, multiprocessing, fork

I have a PyTorch model (class `Net`), together with its saved weights / state dict (`net.pth`), and I want to perform inference in a multiprocessing environment.

I noticed that I cannot simply create a model instance, load the weights, then share the model with a child process (though I'd have assumed this is possible due to copy-on-write). What happens is that the child hangs on `y = model(x)`, and finally the whole program hangs (due to parent's `waitpid`).

The following is a minimal reproducible example:

```py
def handler():
    with torch.no_grad():
        x = torch.rand(1, 3, 32, 32)
        y = model(x)

    return y


model = Net()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load("./net.pth"))

pid = os.fork()

if pid == 0:
    # this doesn't get printed as handler() hangs for the child process
    print('child:', handler())
else:
    # everything is fine here
    print('parent:', handler())
    os.waitpid(pid, 0)
```

If the model loading is done independently for parent & child, i.e. no  sharing, then everything works as expected. I have also tried calling [`share_memory_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.share_memory_) on model's tensors, but to no avail.

Am I doing something obviously wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that sharing the state dict and performing the loading operation in each process solves the problem:

```py
LOADED = False 

def handler():
    global LOADED
    if not LOADED:
        # each process loads state independently
        model.load_state_dict(state)
        LOADED = True

    with torch.no_grad():
        x = torch.rand(1, 3, 32, 32)
        y = model(x)

    return y


model = Net()

# share the state rather than loading the state dict in parent
# model.load_state_dict(torch.load("./net.pth"))
state = torch.load("./net.pth")

pid = os.fork()

if pid == 0:
    print('child:', handler())
else:
    print('parent:', handler())
    os.waitpid(pid, 0)
```